# not set my data in Child position because not available child array

Tags: android

this getItemViewType()

```
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      boolean  type = _arr_GameList.get(position).isFirstComment();
        if (type) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

After that set the view holder type wise but not display data  . i used one arraylist but i want to two arraylist position first parent  and second chhailed position

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       object = _arr_GameList.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            if (object.isFirstComment()) {
                setData(holder, position);
            } else {
                setData(holder, position);
            }
        }
    }
```

After that set the view holder type wise but not display data  . i used one arraylist but i want to two arraylist position first parent  and second chhailed position

```
    private void ReplyCommentServiceCall(final MyViewHolder holder, int position, String comment_id, String comment_body) {
        Call<ResponseBody> call;
        call = LaravelRetrofite.addgetClient().AddreplyComment("Bearer " + preferencesUtility.getAccessToken(), "Application/json", article_id, comment_id, comment_body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.v("Articalereplycomment", response.toString());
                        Log.v("replygetposition", "" + position);

                       boolean type = _arr_GameList.get(position).isFirstComment();
                        Log.v("layouttype", "" + type);
                        object = _arr_GameList.get(position);
                            ArticleCommentsModel articleCommentsModel = _arr_GameList.get(position + 1);
                            articleCommentsModel.setComment_body(comment_body);
                            articleCommentsModel.setDeleteCommentOption("1");
                            articleCommentsModel.setFirstComment(false);
                            _arr_GameList.add(articleCommentsModel);
                            setData(holder, position + 1);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else {
                        // error case
                        switch (response.code()) {
                            case 404:
                                NetworkUtility.ToastFunction(mActivity, "not found");
                                break;
                            case 500:
                                NetworkUtility.ToastFunction(mActivity, "server broken");
                                break;
                            default:
                                NetworkUtility.ToastFunction(mActivity, "unknown error");
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String message = e.getMessage().replace("java.lang.Throwable: ", "");


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v("Upload", t.getMessage());
                String message = t.getMessage().replace("java.lang.Throwable: ", "");
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you got the method right?

right now it seems that this if is useless.
both cases are the same.

```
if (object.isFirstComment()) {
  setData(holder, position);
} else {
  setData(holder, position);
}
```

Comment: its the same method, why do you have an if?